# How to subscribe to the non-free-tier version of Academic Knowledge API?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Their page of Cognitive Services Pricing - Academic Knowledge API (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge-api/)
mentions two ways of using the service:

- **Free** (10,000 transactions free per month), and
- **Standard** ($0.25 per 1000 transaction).

I am wondering if anyone knows how to subscribe to the standard version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described on the page you mentioned:

> As of February 15, 2018, if you’re currently using the Free or
>   Standard tier of the Academic Knowledge API on Azure, you can continue
>   using it with your existing Azure key until May 24, 2018. After this
>   date, please generate new API keys for Free tier usage from the
>   Microsoft Cognitive Services Labs portal. Learn more

So the service is not available through Azure Portal and you must generate a key through `Microsoft Cognitive Services Labs portal`. When you generate this key, you have no option to specify the pricing you want to use, and you don't need an account linked to Azure so there is no pricing linked: you will have a free key.

This is confirmed by the API portal [here](https://dev.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/products?api=56332331778daf02acc0a50b), mentioning:

> Tap into the wealth of academic content in the Microsoft Academic
>   Graph. 10,000 transactions per month, 3 per second for interpret, 1
>   per second for evaluate, 6 per minute for calcHistogram.

As a consequence, there are 2 possibilities:

- you have to send a request to get a standard key
- pricing page is not up-to-date

I would go for the 2nd option as this product has been moved and is only in `experimental` mode.

You can still ask this question on Uservoice, in the topic about Academic Knowledge: https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/555931-project-academic-knowledge

Comment: I found this page posted on 11/12/2018 that tells me how to request a 500G Microsoft Academic Graph on Azure storage (I am still waiting for their approval)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/graph/get-started-setup-provisioning

Comment: My request of the MAG was approved. And here is the message from them: 

Welcome to the Microsoft Academic Graph (MAG) Azure Storage (AS) Distribution preview. Please be advised that this distribution is in free preview stage. Pricing structure is subject to change. 

Your Azure Storage is successfully setup to receive MAG update through Azure Data Factory. The 2019-xx-xx dataset was pushed to your Azure Storage.